# How do I make a table that updates from user input in the box before with tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, python-3.6

The overall aim of the program is to make a scoreboard that displays the scores of both teams and individuals. It needs to contain 4 columns and 5 rows for the team aspect and 20 separate spaces for individual inputs.

I want to make a table that uses user input using the previous box that I had created. So far, I have created up to the point where the user needs to input their team name and displays a table with no entries. I need it to display the events that they are doing as well as the score and their team name/name.

I am new to Python and tkinter so anyone who can help me solve this problem would be great!

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
from time import sleep

def team_name():
    print('Okay, what is your team name?')
    window = Toplevel(main)
    thirdLabel = Label(window, text='Please enter your team name below:', 
bg='black', fg='yellow')
     thirdLabel.pack()
     Label2 = Label(window,text = '')
    Label2.pack(padx=15,pady= 5)
    entry2 = Entry(window,bd =5)
    entry2.pack(padx=15, pady=5)
    buttonconfirm1 = Button(window, text='Confirm',command=confirm1)
    buttonconfirm1.pack()

def confirm1 ():
    window = Toplevel(main)
    confirmLabel = Label(window, text='Scoreboard', bg='black', 
                         fg='yellow')
    confirmLabel.pack(fill=X)

def table ():
    window = Toplevel(main)
    label3 = Label(window, text='Team name/Individual name', bg='black', 
                  fg='yellow')
    label3.pack()
    firstBox = Entry(window, bd=1)
    firstBox.pack()
    secondBox = Entry(window, bd=1)
secondBox.pack()
thirdBox = Entry(window, bd=1)
thirdBox.pack()

def scoreboard():
window = Toplevel(main)
entry_1 = Label(window, text = '')
entry_2 = Label(window, text = '')


def individual_name():
print('Okay, what is you name?')
window = Toplevel(main)
secondLabel = Label(window, text='Please enter your name below', 
                    bg='black', fg='yellow')
secondLabel.pack()
Label1 = Label(window,text = '')
Label1.pack(padx=15,pady= 5)
entry1 = Entry(window,bd =5)
entry1.pack(padx=15, pady=5)
buttonConfirm = Button(window, text='Confirm', command=table)
buttonConfirm.pack()

def confirm ():
window = Toplevel(main)
confirmLabel = Label(window, text='Scoreboard', bg='black', fg='yellow')
confirmLabel.pack(fill=X)

def close():
main.destroy()

main = Tk()
main.maxsize(800,600) 
# Labels section
main_menu_label = Label(main, text='Welcome to the scoreboard! Please 
select from the options below:', bg='Black',
                    fg='white')


# Using a photo for top frame on menu and making a label to place it
photo = PhotoImage(file='Scoreboard.gif')
photo_label = Label(main, image=photo)
photo_label.pack(side=TOP)

# Invisible frames for widget placement
top_frame = Frame(main)
top_frame.pack()
bottom_frame = Frame(main)
bottom_frame.pack(side=BOTTOM)

print('Okay! What is your team name?')

# Buttons for main menu and display on the screen
first_button = Button(top_frame, text='Are you entering as an 
individual?', fg='yellow', bg='black',
                  command=individual_name)
second_button = Button(bottom_frame, text='Are you entering as a team?', 
                       fg='yellow', bg='black', command=team_name)
quit_button = Button(bottom_frame, text='Quit?', fg='yellow', bg='black', 
command=close)

first_button.pack()
second_button.pack()
quit_button.pack()

main.mainloop()
```

Sorry if this is a bit confusing, I can't really explain much more than I already have!

Comment: and what is the problem ? Always show full error message (Traceback) in question (as text, not screenshot)

Comment: use button `{}` to correctly format code in question

Comment: This code is far from Minimal and Complete Example. (no error message and messed up indentation) Please read [MCVE] and edit accordingly.

Comment: A suggestion to make your question less confusing: define the ONE thing you want to do next, and ask a question that allows you to make progress on that.  Un-indented Python is nonsense, so you *must* fix your indentation.  Proofread it until it's correct.